# How to return JSON in django

Tags: json, django-forms, django-views

I want to return only JSON data for this view method and I'm not sure if I'm doing it the right way. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
def helpful_click(request,object):
    if request.POST and request.is_ajax():
        form = HelpfulForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return simplejson.dumps({'helpful':True})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My understanding is that every Django view should return an `HttpResponse` object, and you should also make sure the mime-type is set correctly:

http://jibbering.com/blog/?p=514

In a project I was working on I had something like this:

```
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'helpful':True}), 'application/json')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`JsonResponse` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects):

```
>>> from django.http import JsonResponse
>>> response = JsonResponse({'foo': 'bar'})
>>> response.content
b'{"foo": "bar"}'
```